# Common Lisp Inferior Lisp Buffer in Emacs

Tags: emacs, process, lisp, common-lisp, elisp

I am wondering why the Common Lisp buffer in Emacs is called "Inferior Lisp"? That is, inferior to what? What is the reason?

Also, is it correct to understand that that buffer is basically a shell that runs an implementation of Lisp, very similar to how one runs it in a terminal?

Lastly, how do things like SLIME and Slynk tie into this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [emacs.se] would be a better place to ask about the design and philosophy of Emacs.

Comment: I think "inferior" might be old ITS terminology for subprocesses, and the name is intended to distinguish it from the mode used for editing Lisp source code. It does indeed use the same underlying mechanisms as shell mode, augmented with commands specific to Lisp.

Comment: I also think this is off-topic, but an inferior process is one which is further down the process tree on Unix-like systems: all processes are inferior to `init` (or whatever the initial process is), and a given process may have one or more children with the parent/child structure being defined by `getppid(2)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean buffer `*inferior-lisp`, which is created by command `inferior-lisp`, then the meaning derives from the fact that it is the output of an "inferior" process.

`C-h f inferior-lisp` tells you:

> Run an inferior Lisp process, input and output via buffer `*inferior-lisp*`.
>
> If there is a process already running in `*inferior-lisp*`, just switch
>   to that buffer.
>
> With argument, allows you to edit the command line (default is value
>   of ‘inferior-lisp-program’).  Runs the hooks from
>   `inferior-lisp-mode-hook` (after the `comint-mode-hook` is run).
>
> (Type `?` in the process buffer for a list of commands.)

And `C-h v inferior-lisp-program` tells you:

> Program name for invoking an inferior Lisp in Inferior Lisp mode.
>
> You can customize this variable.

See the Emacs manual, node [External Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/External-Lisp.html) (the node title is **Running an External Lisp**) for information about running an external Lisp session. It tells you, for example:

> You can run an external Lisp session as a subprocess or **“inferior
>   process”** of Emacs, and pass expressions to it to be evaluated.

The subprocess, or "inferior" process, is run from the Emacs process (session).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16591485/729907) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39271651/729907) about "inferior" process/program/shell.